# Declare array of objects when the class has more then one default constructor C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Hello I have `class point` and the job is to make `array of points` (objects of the same class), but the class has more than one constructor. How to declare which one of them I want in my array? The code:

```
class point
{
private:
    double pointX, pointY;
    string color;
    int form;
public:
    point();
    point(double, double, string color = "red", int form = 2);
    point(string color = "red", int form = 2);
    ~point() {
        cout << "Deleting object point" << endl;
    }
    inline void print();
    inline void distance();
};

point::point(double x, double y, string color = "red", int form = 2) {
    cout << "enter x coordinate of the point x = "; cin >> pointX;
    cout << "enter y coordinate of the point y = "; cin >> pointY;
}

point::point(string color = "red", int form = 2) {
    cout << "enter x coordinate of the point x = "; cin >> pointX;
    cout << "enter y coordinate of the point y = "; cin >> pointY;
}

point::point() {
    cout << "enter x coordinate of the point x = "; cin >> pointX;
    cout << "enter y coordinate of the point y = "; cin >> pointY;
    cout << "enter color of the point "; getline(cin, color);
    cout << "enter number form 1 - 3 for the form of the point "; cin >> form;
}

inline void point::print() {
    cout << "the x coordinate of the point is x = " << pointX << endl;
    cout << "the y coordiante of the point is y = " << pointY << endl;
    cout << "the color of the point is " << color << endl;
    if (form = 1) cout << "the form is circle" << endl;
    if (form = 2) cout << "the form is square" << endl;
    if (form = 2) cout << "the form is cross" << endl;
}

inline void point::distance() {
    double z;
    z = sqrt(pointX*pointX + pointY*pointY);
    cout << "distance between the point and the start of coordinate system is " << z << endl;
}

double pointDistatnce() {
    double z, x, y;
    point points = new point[4];
}
```

```
!!! point points = new point[4];` // here must be the array of objects but it shows me error that "class point has more than one default constructor"?
```

And I want to use the constructor without parameters so for the user to construct his own point. Here are the errors from the error list;

```
!! no suitable constructor exists to convert from "point    
!! class "point" has more than one default constructor
```

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to chose between two default constructors?

Comment: Make your class have one unambiguous default constructor. Only you know what you want to do when no arguments are given. Make *one* thing that does that.

Comment: A class cannot have more than one default constructor, so the question is moot.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's not true. In `struct S { S(int i = 0) {} S() {} };`, you have two default constructors. See §12.1/4: "A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that either has no parameters or else each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument."

Comment: @ChristianHackl OK, a class can have an infinite number of default constructors. You just can't use any of them.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Strange, isn't it? I wonder if there is a defect report for this, or if there is some way you could use more of them.

Answer (score 3):

`point();` declares a default constructor.  So does `point(string color = "red", int form = 2);`  Either get rid of the first one and just use the second, or get rid of the default value for `color` in the second.

Edit based on the extra info you posted:  You are looking for the compiler to read the programmer's mind.  You defined a constructor with no parameters that does one thing, but you defined a constructor with two optional parameters that does a different thing.  When the constructor is invoked and given no parameters, does that mean it should execute with no parameters or does it mean it should execute with the default values for the two optional parameters.

None of that changes my original answer.  It just means you need to think a bit in order to use that answer.  In the partial code you initially provided, one might hope that the two constructors that each could be invoked with no parameters were redundant with each other, so just dropping the redundancy would fix it.  But since you want the programmer to be able to invoke one of two different constructors, you need to think of a way to tell the compiler which one should be used.

While rethinking your design, you should also try to drop the idea of using `cin` within a constructor.  It is not technically **wrong**.  But it is a bad enough idea that you shouldn't do it.